# mass declaring fields with appropriate access identifier

Tags: java

good day!

I apologize if this question has been asked already, I was unable to find relevant information online.

say I am declaring 10 different private fields for a java Class. in C++ I could do:

```
private:

int a;
int b;
int c;
...
```

but in java that syntax is disallowed and the only way I know is:

```
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;
...
```

I was wondering if a java equivalent of the first method is available.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reference. a shame I was unable to find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    private int a, b, c, d;
}
```